# How to add a different Stack Overflow account to existing Stack Overflow careers?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

I had a Stack Overflow account which was linked to my Stack Overflow career. Now I can't login to that account, this is a different problem. So I created another account and I want to link my current account to my existing career account. But when I click the edit button, it shows me the previous account by default and there is no option to link my new account. Please help me on this. I need to link my new account. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: best to contact team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: Actually careers@stackoverflow.com is the address to use for Careers queries... But don't worry I'm taking a look now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated your Careers account to not be linked to a Stack Exchange account.

If you go to your profile you will now be able to link your new account to it :)

Comment: Thanks, Now I can link my current account. Can you help me to get the reputation and activities of my old account to new account?

Comment: You'll need to contact team@stackoverflow.com to get that addressed.